# Convert string to filestream in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, filestream

Just started with writing unit tests and I am now, blocked with this situation:

I have a method which has a FileStream object and I am trying to pass a "string" to it. 
So, I would like to convert my string to FileStream and I am doing this:

```
File.WriteAllText(string.Concat(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%temp%"),   
 @"/test.txt"), testFileContent); //writes my string to a temp file!


new FileStream(string.Concat(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%temp%"),  
    @"/test.txt"), FileMode.Open) //open that temp file and uses it as a fileStream!
```

close the file then!

But, I guess there must be some very simple alternative to convert a string to a fileStream.

Suggestions are welcome! [Note there are other answers to this question in stackoverflow but none seems to be a straight forward solution to that]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21):

First of all change your method to allow `Stream` instead of `FileStream`. `FileStream` is an implementation which, as I remember, does not add any methods or properties, just implement abstract class `Stream`. And then using below code you can convert `string` to `Stream`:

```
public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot change the code. It's a library which is already compiled and I don't have a source code!

Comment: So override `FileStream` with your own class.

Comment: you will have to mock the filestream then as mentioned by others

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. You said this was for unit testing; why are you unit testing a method that you cannot change?

Comment: @RowlandShaw to be sure the method someone else made works as expected.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Whilst a useful thing to do for acceptance testing, that doesn't make it a good candidate for _unit_ testing

Comment: I don't distinguish those categories.  It's just tests.

Answer (score 2):

As FileStream class provides a stream for a file and hence it's constructor requires the path of the file,mode, permission parameter etc. to read the file into stream and hence it is used to read the text from file into stream. If we need to convert string to stream first we need to convert string to bytes array as stream is a sequence of bytes. Below is the code.

```
   //Stream is a base class it holds the reference of MemoryStream
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            String strText = "This is a String that needs to beconvert in stream";
             byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);
             stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
             //set the position at the beginning.
             stream.Position = 0;
             using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                           string strData;
                           while ((strData= sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(strData);
                            }
                        }
```